# Trying to run c code in VS code or compiling it using gcc error

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to study/train for a college and I'm having one problem with all the example code they have. Example :

```
int     ft_putchar(char c);

void    ft_print_alphabet(void)
{
    char    letter;

    letter = 'a';
    while (letter <= 'z')
    {
        ft_putchar(letter);
        letter++;
    }
}
```

When i try to run it in VS code i get an error saying:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\BRUNOB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCVxBIA.o:testc.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `ft_putchar' 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

same error when i try to compile the file using "gcc testc.c -o testc"

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Where did you defined `int ft_putchar(char c)` ?

Comment: From the way you are compiling it, it looks like you need to define the entrypoint, simplest being, writing the "int main() { ... }` function and also write an implementation for the `ft_putchar(char)` function. Right now the linked does not know where to look for `ft_putchar` and the `main` function.

Comment: You've two options here – first is to `#include <your_header.h>` where `ft_putchar` is defined or, add the header file where it's defined in your compilation option.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux and i assume that you want low level io using [write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) like,

```c
#include<unistd.h>

int ft_putchar(char c)
{
   // STDOUT_FILENO is 1 or fileno(stdout) from stdio.h
   write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
}

void ft_print_alphabet(void)
{
    char letter;

    letter = 'a';

    while (letter <= 'z')
    {
        ft_putchar(letter); // or just call putchar(letter) from stdio.h
        letter++;
    }
}

int main()
{
   ft_print_alphabet();
   return 0;
}
```

Note : if you are using windows see write [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/write?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Nope I'm using windows ( i tried your code and it worked in VS code ) the problem is that the code i copied is the answer to the exercise and its how we are supposed to answer :/

Comment: I have posted a link for _write function, so i think you can easily change above code by using `#include<io.h>`

Comment: or just use `putchar from stdio.h` if you have trouble in this.

Comment: could you please tell what error you are facing ?

Comment: the same one I posted

Comment: The first error says that you didn't defined ft_putchar and second error says than you didn't defined main function but i defined both of them in above code the only thing you want is to change is may be  `#include<unistd.h>` to `#include<io.h>` and `write` to `_write`, Try this :-)

Comment: if you are not restricted to use low level io, i strongly recommend to use putchar from stdio.h